# mysqli not working on command line

Tags: php, apache, command-line, mysqli

I am having a problem which I still could not find any resource to help me with it. I hope it can be solved here. I am kind of newbie on php, so Im sorry if it's very simple.

I have a php script, which connects to a database mysql, running under a xampp (apache 2.4 and php 5.4) on windows 8. This script works fine on my browser but when I try executing it through command line (cmd), it won't work and returns me this error:

**Notice: Undefined variable: dbhandle in C:\xampp\htdocs\4sq-pull\_get_weather.ph
p on line 29
Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in C:\xampp
\htdocs\4sq-pull_get_weather.php on line 30**

- I have the extension=php_mysqli.dll uncommented
- I've set the variables PATH and PATHTEXT
- I am using this command line to run the script: c:\xampp\php\php.exe -f c:\xampp\htdocs\4sq-pull\_get_weather.php

For last, my php code is something like this:

```
<?php
$username = "xxx";
$password = "xxx";
$hostname = "localhost"; 
$database = "4sq";
//connection to the database
$dbhandle = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $database)
  or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
 mysqli_select_db($dbhandle, "4sq");
?>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Nothing changes with that, but thanks anyways. Actually I only added this function cos I had no more hopes and was trying anything people were saying on internet! btw, weird that stackoverflow is not displaying the command line right. The right one should have a counter slash before the php file name: c:\xampp\php\php.exe -f c:\xampp\htdocs\4sq-pull\_get_weather.php

Comment: (Your counter slash issue is due to the underline character being use for _italics_ formatting, and the \ escapes that – so I fixed that for you, by using a double counter slash – I think that’s what you meant?)

Comment: If it was establishing the connection that was not working, your `or die(…)` should give you a message telling you that – but the error tells you something completely different! I assume you’re including this script into another one? Then maybe the `include_path` setting for execution via command line is different, or the working directory of the script – so the include fails, and `$dbhandle` is indeed undefined. (Using `require` instead of `include` would have alerted you to that in the first place – so in the future use that for _essential_ includes.)

Comment: CBroe, the problem is something like that. First i tried changing the include to the require, but it still not worked. So i ended up trying to hard code the db connection into the script i am calling, and it worked! It seems that, via command line, theres some sort of problem with my includes/requires. Weird.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code i made

```
<?php
$DATABASE_IP = "";
$DATABASE_NAME = "";
$DATABASE_PROXY = "";

$DATABASE_ADMIN_USERNAME = "";
$DATABASE_ADMIN_PASSWORD = "";

$link = mysql_connect($DATABASE_IP, $DATABASE_NAME, $DATABASE_ADMIN_PASSWORD);

if(!$DATABASE_IP == "string")
{
    echo "please fill in required field *IP<br/>";
} else {
    echo "";
}

if(!$DATABASE_NAME == "string")
{
    echo "please fill in required field *Name<br/>";
} else {
    echo "";
}

if(!$link){
    die('sorry could not connect at this time )=<br/>' . mysql_error());
}
echo "connected";

mysql_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: How’s that supposed to help with the specific problem …?

Comment: his code may have had a issue i posted this so he could see if it was his code or not

Comment: So basically your answer is just a wild guess – that’s not really helpful. Please restrict your answers to cases where you _know_ what the problem is and how to fix it.